# Does Akka.net actor suitable for GET and Search Operation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, akka, akka-http, akka.net

We are using akka.net actor model in current project. I used an entity actor to handle insert, update and delete operations on it. In a case of search or get does actor model not suit?

If it is support in UI how it possible to get result (weather to used Ask function)

Does it not good practice to use akka.net actor model for get and query data?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a some equivalent of `GetState` operation, however IMHO in case of UI, I think that much better is to perform a conceptual switch. Instead of making UI asking if state of an actor has changes, you could subscribe client to get updates about actor state changes when they actually happen.

[Akka.Streams](http://getakka.net/docs/streams/quickstart) is particularly nice and handy to implement this sort of functionality ;)